# Create keystore entry with gradle

Tags: android, gradle, keystore

I can create new apps with different package names from my project, but I also need to sign them.

Is it possible to use gradle for creating new keystore entries?

Comment: Have you looked at the chapter in the Gradle user guide titled "The Signing Plugin"?  How about you read that and see how far that gets you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I´ve found the minimal command to create new certificates with a single command

> **keytool -genkeypair -alias yourAlias -validity 90 -storepass myKeystorePassword -keypass myKeyPassword -keystore myKeystorePath -dname 'cn=myName'**